# Copy list item from xml view SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, xml, fragment, sapui5

Got a simple question, from controller, i want to copy list item template that is defined as xml fragment. So far i've managed to copy the template **only once**, the problem is that i cant **copy more than once**

my code:

```
var button = oEvent.getSource();
var id = button.data("id");
var list = button.getParent().getParent();
var newItem = new sap.m.CustomListItem();
newItem.addContent(this[id]);
list.addItem(newItem);
```

where this[id] is actualy defined CustomListItem xml fragment:

```
this.volumes = sap.ui.xmlfragment("fragment.volumes", this);
this.getView().addDependent(this.volumes);
```

is it possible to copy of xml template?

there is no errors in console, just **empty new generated** customListItem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I suggest reviewing the [the docs for aggregation binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/97830de2d7314e93b5c1ee3878a17be9)

I think what you might be trying to achieve is something like this:

```
//check if the template has already been loaded, otherwise load it 
if (!this._oTemplate) {
    this._oTemplate = sap.ui.xmlfragment("path.to.fragment");
}

//clone the template to create a new item
var oNewItem = this._oTemplate.clone();

//add the clone to the list
oList.addItem(oNewItem);
```

When you use an XML fragment to create the item, only 1 item exists. So if you try to add the same item to the list more than once, you won't see a new item show up (since there is only 1 of them). Using `clone()` creates another item.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i've managed to copy the template, by defining each time new this.volumes1, 2 ,3 and etc, depends on list items length